# How to get login username using task scheduler?

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

I have search similar article but don't have the correct answer.

I have a schedule task using gpo which using %USERNAME% to get the current logged username but it returns the username which the task is running under, which is always the same user - I want to know the username that has logged on.

Comment: Check `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" -v *`. Choose a value (e.g. `LastLoggedOnUser`) and then you can parse `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" -v LastLoggedOnUser` using a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try running $ query user command which will show currently logged on users with the login status and logon time.

```
query user
```

For more information refer to: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user